# Issue with merging time series variables to create new DataFrame with arbitrary index

Tags: python, join, merge, pandas

So I am trying to merge the following columns of data which are currently indexed as daily entries (but only have points once per week). I have separated the columns into year variables but am having trouble getting them into a combined dataframe and disregard the date index so that I can build out min/max columns by week over the years. I am not sure how to get merge/join function to do this.

#Create year variables, append to new dataframe with new index

I have the following:

```
def minmaxdata():
   Totrigs =   dataforgraphs()
   tr = Totrigs
   yrs=[tr['2007'],tr['2008'],tr['2009'],tr['2010'],tr['2011'],tr['2012'],tr['2013'],tr['2014']]
   yrlist = ['tr07','tr08','tr09','tr10','tr11','tr12','tr13','tr14']
   dic = dict(zip(yrlist,yrs))
   yr07,yr08,yr09,yr10,yr11,yr12,yr13,yr14    =dic['tr07'],dic['tr08'],dic['tr09'],dic['tr10'],dic['tr11'],dic['tr12'],dic['tr13'],dic['tr14']


   minmax = yr07.append([yr08,yr09,yr10,yr11,yr12,yr13,yr14],ignore_index=True)

I would like a Dataframe like the following:

   2007  2008 2009 2010 2011 2012 2013 2014  min max 

1   10    13   10    12   34  23   22   14   10  34  
2   25    ...
3   22
4   ...
5
.
.
.  ...
52
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your original data look like, but I don't think it's a good idea to hard-code all years. You lose re-usability. I'll setup a sequence of random integers indexed by date with one date per week.

```
In [65]: idx = pd.date_range ('2007-1-1','2014-12-31',freq='W')

In [66]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(100, size=len(idx)), index=idx, columns=['value']) 

In [67]: df.head()
Out[67]: 
            value
2007-01-07      7
2007-01-14      2
2007-01-21     85
2007-01-28     55
2007-02-04     36

In [68]: df.tail()
Out[68]: 
            value
2014-11-30     76
2014-12-07     34
2014-12-14     43
2014-12-21     26
2014-12-28     17
```

Then get `year` of the week:

```
In [69]: df['year'] = df.index.year

In [70]: df['week'] = df.groupby('year').cumcount()+1
```

(You may try `df.index.week` for week# but I've seen weird behavior like starting from week #53 in Jan.)

Finally, do a pivot table to transform and get row-wise `max/min`:

```
In [71]: df2 = df.pivot_table(index='week', columns='year', values='value')

In [72]: df2['max'] = df2.max(axis=1)

In [73]: df2['min'] = df2.min(axis=1)
```

And now our dataframe `df2` looks like this and should be what you need:

```
In [74]: df2
Out[74]: 
year  2007  2008  2009  2010  2011  2012  2013  2014  max  min
week                                                          
1        7    82    13    32    24    58    18    10   82    7
2        2     5    29     0     2    97    59    83   97    0
3       85    89     8    83    63    73    47    49   89    8
4       55     5     1    44    78    10    13    87   87    1
5       36    41    48    98    98    24    24    69   98   24
6       51    43    62    60    44    57    34    33   62   33
7       37    66    72    46    28    11    73    36   73   11
8       30    13    86    93    46    67    95    15   95   13
9       78    84    16    21    70    39    43    90   90   16
10       9     2    88    15    39    81    44    96   96    2
11      34    76    16    44    44    26    30    77   77   16
12       2    24    23    13    25    69    25    74   74    2
13      66    91    67    77    18    47    95    66   95   18
14      59    52    22    42    40    99    88    21   99   21
15      76    17    31    57    43    31    91    67   91   17
16      76    38    53    43    84    45    78     9   84    9
17      88    53    34    22    99    93    61    42   99   22
18      78    19    82    19     5    80    55    69   82    5
19      54    92    56     6     2    85     7    67   92    2
20       8    56    86    41    60    76    31    81   86    8
21      64    76    11    38    41    98    39    72   98   11
22      21    86    34     1    15    27    26    95   95    1
23      82    90     3    17    62    18    93    20   93    3
24      47    42    32    27    83     8    22    14   83    8
25      15    66    70    16     4    22    26    14   70    4
26      12    68    21     7    86     2    27    10   86    2
27      85    85     9    39    17    94    67    42   94    9
28      73    80    96    49    46    23    69    84   96   23
29      57    74     6    71    79    31    79     7   79    6
30      18    84    85    34    71    69     0    62   85    0
31      24    40    93    53    72    46    44    71   93   24
32      95     4    58    57    68    27    95    71   95    4
33      65    84    87    41    38    45    71    33   87   33
34      62    14    41    83    79    63    44    13   83   13
35      49    96    50    62    25    45    69    63   96   25
36       6    38    86    34    98    60    67    80   98    6
37      99    44    26    19    19    20    57    17   99   17
38       2    40     7    65    68    58    68    13   68    2
39      72    31    83    65    69    39    10    76   83   10
40      90    31    42    20     7     8    62    79   90    7
41      10    46    82    96    30    43    12    84   96   10
42      79    38    28    78    25     9    80     2   80    2
43      64    83    63    40    29    86    10    15   86   10
44      89    91    62    48    53    69    16     0   91    0
45      99    26    85    45    26    53    79    86   99   26
46      35    14    46    25    74     6    68    44   74    6
47      17     9    84    88    29    83    85     1   88    1
48      18    69    55    16    77    35    16    76   77   16
49      60     4    36    50    81    28    50    34   81    4
50      36    29    38    28    81    86    71    43   86   28
51      41    82    95    27    95    77    74    26   95   26
52       2    81    89    82    28     2    11    17   89    2
53     NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN   NaN     0   NaN   NaN    0    0
```

EDIT:
If you need `max/min` over a certain columns, just list them. In this case (2007-2013), they are consecutive so you can do the following.

```
df2['max_2007to2013'] = df2[range(2007,2014)].max(axis=1)
```

If not, simply list them like: `df2[[2007,2010,2012,2013]].max(axis=1)`

Comment: Thank you! I got it after realizing a mistake I had been making. As a last follow up question, is it posssible with the min/max columns to set the years included in the min/max. In my case, I would only like to include 2007-2013 not 2014.

Comment: I really appreciate your help on this. If you can see my above question would really help finish up this last part. Just wondering about how to index the min/max over certain years.

Comment: Hey tried both methods you suggested but am getting 'Key Error range(2007,2013)', not sure if you can list them. Any idea why?

Comment: Your column names might be `str` not `int`, i.e., '2007' not 2007. Try `df[['2007','2008','2009']]`

Comment: Tried that, I get the error: KeyError: "['2007' '2008' '2009' '2010' '2011' '2012' '2013'] not in index". When I take our the extra brackets I get the error: KeyError: 'Key length (7) was greater than MultiIndex lexsort depth (2)'

Comment: Any suggestions? Still stuck here

Comment: Do you have commas in between? (You need them, and also two pairs of brackets)

Comment: Yes had both. The second error seems to be where the issue is.

Comment: I think because the pivot table is indexed by week, it cant be called by column. Thanks again for all your help, are you a friend of Sankalp?

Comment: Index has nothing to do with columns. Examine what your dataframe column dtype: `print df2.columns` It should tell you whether it's 'int' or 'object'.   I've no idea who Sankalp is.

Comment: As a last resort, you should be able to get all columns except last one by `df2[df2.columns[:-1]]`